# How can I track who entered a comment on a TFS Work Item

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

When working on an issue in other bug-tracking systems there are ways to add notes to items that are clearly marked with the authors user name and the date entered. I'm looking for a similar feature in TFS's work items. **Is there such a feature?**

We currently use a system that allows us to hit a hot-key to paste the current time and username into the multi-line text fields. All users know to paste that info in above what they type. While this is manual, it's acceptable and easy. For example:

```
5/1/2009 1:20:00 am - AManagr-
Defered to next version, and here's why...

4/24/2009 1:20:00 am - ADev - 
QA machine had out of date XYZ gizmo component. Here's the convoluted way this can happen... blah blah... This is difficult to fix.

4/22/2009 1:20:00 am - QAGuy - 
I can't save reports to PDF files.
```

Other tools I've used (Mantis maybe?) had a "Notes" feature baked in. So I couldn't forget to put my name on comments, or know if new notes go to the top or bottom of a field, etc...

Manually typing your name and the date/time isn't a (good) option. But, hitting a single key, or toolbar button would be OK.

I'm not looking for advice on decomposing long-form "notes" like this into multiple specific individual fields. Also, I am aware of the history tab on work items, but this isn't sufficient. Who wrote what and when needs to be clear and in the same view as the text.

**Update**

Imagine several team members researching an issue. They all add info to the work item, each appending more text to the same field. How do you easily know who added what part?

The History log shows a line for each user's change and even shows the field's change. But that is on another screen and is hard to mentally parse the data it shows.

They could "sign" each part of the text - but this is a pain without help from the tool.

Maybe Stackoverflows comments feature is a good example as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. TFS work items are customizable. Not as much as I would like in this version but you can do what you want.

Lets take a stab at it with the following field definitions. The Notes Date and Notes Author are readonly and get their default values from the system. Notes field is HTML and you can put whatever you want in there. You can do this in the [TFS Process Editor](https://web.archive.org/web/20200923032924/http://geekswithblogs.net/jkurtz/archive/2008/01/24/118864.aspx).

```
 <FIELD reportable="dimension" type="DateTime" name="Notes Date" refname="System.VSTS.Notes.Date">
    <DEFAULT from="clock" />
    <READONLY not="[Global]\Team Foundation Administrators" />
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD reportable="dimension" type="String" name="Notes Author" refname="System.VSTS.Notes.Author">
    <DEFAULT from="currentuser" />
    <READONLY not="[Global]\Team Foundation Administrators" />
  </FIELD>
  <FIELD type="HTML" name="Notes" refname="System.VSTS.Notes" />
</FIELDS>
```

Of course you will still need to add controls to your form.

Another thing you can try is only keep the Notes field and register for a WorkItemChanged event and write a webservice to update the notes field with the Date and Author. Changed BY and Changed Date fields will give you this information. You can learn about the available events and how to subscribe to them in this article by Brian A. Randell - [Team Foundation System Event Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/may/team-system-team-foundation-server-event-service)

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://mynamespace.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class UpdateWorkItem : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private static TeamFoundationServer _Tfs;
    private static WorkItemStore _WorkItemStore;

    private static List<WorkItem> _ChangedWorkItems = new List<WorkItem>();
  
    [SoapDocumentMethod(Action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify", RequestNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03")]
    [WebMethod]
    public void Notify(string eventXml, string tfsIdentityXml)
    {

        EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services", "Log Started: Notify Webmethod");


        // Load the recieved XML into a XMLDocument
        XmlDocument eventXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        eventXmlDoc.LoadXml(eventXml);
        XmlElement eventData = eventXmlDoc.DocumentElement;

        // Validate event data
        if (eventData != null)
        {
            // Get Work Item id from event data
            int id = GetWorkItemId(eventData);

            //EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services", String.Format("eventXmlDoc {0}", eventXmlDoc.InnerXml));
            EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services", String.Format("Got Id {0}", id));
            string changedby = GetWorkItemChangedBy(eventData);
            EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services", String.Format("Got changedby {0}", changedby));
            if (changedby != "TFSSERVICE")
            {
                //Add a 15 second delay in order to make sure all workitems are saved first before starting to update them
                Thread.Sleep(15000);
                EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services", "Calling UpdateWorkItemInternal");
                UpdateWorkItemInternal(id);
            }
        }
    }

    private int GetWorkItemId(XmlElement eventData)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(eventData.SelectSingleNode("CoreFields/IntegerFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.Id']/NewValue").InnerText);
    }

    private string GetWorkItemChangedBy(XmlElement eventData)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(eventData.SelectSingleNode("CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.ChangedBy']/NewValue").InnerText);
    }

    private static void UpdateWorkItemInternal(int id)
    {
        //Connect To TFS Server 
        EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services", string.Format("Updating Work Item {0}", id));
        _Tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer("TeamServer");

        _WorkItemStore = (WorkItemStore)_Tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
        WorkItem workItem = _WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem(id);

        switch ((string)workItem.Fields["System.WorkItemType"].Value)
        {
            case "Bug":
                UpdateNotes(workItem);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        foreach (WorkItem item in _ChangedWorkItems)
        {
            if (item.IsDirty)
            {
                foreach (Field field in item.Fields)
                {
                    if (!field.IsValid)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Not valid");
                    }
                }
                EventLog.WriteEntry("TFS Services", string.Format("Saving WorkItem: {0}", item.Id));
                try
                {
                    item.Save();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        _ChangedWorkItems.Clear();
    }
    
    private static void UpdateNotes(WorkItem workItem)
    {
       Field notes = workitem.Fields["System.VSTS.Notes"];
       if (notes != null)
       {
         notes = string.Format("{0} - {1}", workItem.ChangedDate, workItem.ChangedBy);
       } 

       if (workItem.IsDirty)
       {
           if (!_ChangedWorkItems.Contains(workItem))
           {
               _ChangedWorkItems.Add(workItem);
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

This is just quick and dirty with some copy and paste from my existing code so review it carefully to make sure I didn't introduce a typo.

Comment: Your first suggestion just shows the last person who updated that Notes field? That's useful - but not exactly it. I think the second example may do what I want. I'd want to append this info only when notes was changed - but I think that's an easy addition. I'd love a solution that would be applied interactively (vs. X seconds after saving)

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the issue with the History tab? It contains the date/time and the user's name in a grey bar with the comment they made immediately below it.

If they didn't make a comment, but made other changes to the work item there will be a collapsed heading called Show Changed Fields. The comment is always visible though.

**Update**

You could create a custom work item control that provides your own view of the work item's history.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286959.aspx

See also [TFS Work Item Tracking Custom Controls](http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/)